# Faster Way For Graphics In Visual Studios?

Tags: c#, c++

In Visual Studios, using the Graphics class, if you try to clear the screen and draw graphics afterwards it won't be able to keep up and will cause a terrible flicker.

Is there a faster way to do this?

I want to be able to draw graphics on the screen and clear them fast enough to keep up with movement. Kind of like how OpenGL works.

Comment: The flicker you're noticing is probably from not double buffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use double buffering. Basically you draw the next image off screen in advance and then move it into view to avoid the flickering effect. C# has a [BufferedGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics.aspx) class. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer) will probably help too.

Comment: Nevermind. I managed to figure out, thanks to that Microsoft link you gave me and some deep thought. Thanks!